# Web scraping fund data from Yahoo finance using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape 3 items from a Yahoo Finance web page given a mutual fund or ETF symbol: The fund name, its expense ratio, and its net assets. I'm new to web scraping, am unfamiliar with CSS and XML and have read about rvest and the SelectorGadget tool.  The good news is that I can pretty much scrape the fund name.

For this example, I am using the ticker "FNDB".  The information is on either of these two pages - I show both in case one is easier to use than another, but my code uses the first:

[Summary page](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FNDB?p=FNDB)
[Profile page](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FNDB/profile?p=FNDB)

Here is the code and result for extracting the title:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FNDB?p=FNDB"
#Reading the HTML code from the website
webpage <- read_html(url)
code <- "title"
result <- html_nodes(webpage,code)
result
```

> {xml_nodeset (1)}
>   [1] FNDB : Summary for Schwab Fundamental U.S. Broad M - Yahoo Finance\n

That's not exactly what I am looking for because the result contains more information than I'd like, but I can work with it.  Help here would be appreciated, but I'm mainly looking for guidance on the codes to extract the net assets and expense ratio information.  Absent that, I would appreciate being pointed to where I can learn how to figure out the codes.  Using SelectorGadget returns "No valid path found."  Thank you.

Comment: No idea how r works so no idea about rvest either. But you have to pass this as a selector '[data-test=NET_ASSETS-value] span' for net_assets and '[data-test=EXPENSE_RATIO-value] span' for expense ratio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just get the entire table, consider this

```
result <- html_nodes(webpage, "#quote-summary")
result <- html_nodes(result, "table") %>% html_table()
```

Answer (score 1):

I add a hard time figuring out `rvest` and SelectorGadget, too. Somebody smarter can use the CSS Selectors, but I had to use the XPATH Selectors. Here's some functions to accomplish your tasks. Bear in mind the output of these are characters and would need to be converted to numeric.

```
library(rvest)

get_url <- function(sym) {
  out <- paste0("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/", sym, "/profile?p=", sym)
}

get_name <- function(sym) {
  url <- get_url(sym)
  name <- read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = 
      '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "Mend(40px)", " " ))]') %>%
    html_text()
  return(name)
}

get_ratio <- function(sym) {
  url <- get_url(sym)
  out <- read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = 
      '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "Ta(e)", " " ))]') %>%
    html_text()
  return(out[4])
}

get_assets <- function(sym) {
  url <- get_url(sym)
  out <- read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = 
      '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "Fl(end)", " " ))]') %>%
    html_text()
  return(out[6])
}
```

Comment: Brian's post is helpful. Is there a resource one would suggest for figuring out the text assigned to the xpath parameter in case I want to find other elements?